# Aptana Studio 3 doesn't work after upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, java, openjdk

When I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 Aptana Studio 3 doesn't work any more. When I try to open it after a few minutes it just closes, but when I open it in the terminal I got this error massage.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xa144786d, pid=3011, tid=3076155136

JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_51-b31) (build 1.7.0_51-b31)
Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86 )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x5486d]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x1d

 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /opt/Aptana_Studio_3/hs_err_pid3011.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please include 
 instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I tried to reinstall that frame using Synaptic, but it doesn't work. After that, I uninstall Aptana Studio. I installed it by this [manual](http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/) . I have used this manual before upgrade and after upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem after upgrading to UBUNTU 14.04. For a workaround I added the following line to the end of "**AptanaStudio3.ini**" file (in your case it should be at '*/opt/Aptana_Studio_3/AptanaStudio3.ini*')

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

That worked for me (at least for the past hour since it used to close after few minutes), I hope it solves your problem as well.

Comment: thanks for response, but i managed to fix problem by installing Oracle java by this manual http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux. But i gonna keep in mind your response because you can never know when you will need ir ;)

Comment: worked for me! thanks you saved me so much cursing

Comment: for some time worked my found cure but  few weeks ago it crashed again but no fixed with  editing aptana.ini as mentioned above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of thinks, this worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04 + java 7 oracle): In a terminal:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

And it worked (until now)

Answer (score 0):

-- never mind this didnt work after all --

I read somewhere that theres a problem with OpenJDK and its best to use OracleJDK.
You can try remove OpenJDK first as i did or just go ahead and install OracleJDK.

These lines seem to fix it for me.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: also i did actually blank my aptana.ini as well